# Export products using cron job Magento 2.1.x

Tags: products, cron, export, magento-2.1.7

I need to export products several times a day using cron job. I have little experience with Magento 2.1 and I don't know how to develop the script.
I hope you can help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a console command in magento to run the following

   ```
    $attributes = ['entity_id','sku', 'name', 'type_id', 'status', 'visibility', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
   $collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create();


           $output = fopen('php://stdout','w');

           $collection = $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

           foreach ($collection as $item) {
               $line = array();
               foreach ($attributes as $attributeCode) {
                   $attr = $item->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode);
                   if ($attr->usesSource()) {
                       $line[$attributeCode] = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($item->getData($attributeCode));
                   } else {
                       $line[$attributeCode] = $item->getData($attributeCode);
                   }
               }
               fputcsv($output, $line);
           }
   ```
2. create a cron to run this script time to time.